# Bind to textbox with string.format

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to make the binding work with string format?

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
          <EditItemTemplate>

              <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Foramt("{0:#,###}",Bind("Price")) %>' />

          </EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the following overload which allows you to specify the format:

```
<%# Bind("Price", "{0:#,###}") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use overload form of DataBinder.Eval

```
<%# Eval("Price", "{0:#,###}") %>
```

Using Bind

```
<%= Bind("price", "{0:#,###}") %>
```