# How to format mssql datetime column to display only time on web page input field?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

Using **ASP.NET** and **MSSQL**

I have simple datetime column

**OUTPUT:** `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

I am aware in sql I can do:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)
```

**OUTPUT:** `00:00:00`

Also `dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}"` does not seem to work with input fields.

---

*I have heard strong arguments for NOT **converting** in sql and instead to use **formatting** on the web page.*

---

**QUESTION**

With that in mind what is good practice for formatting datetime attached to an input string purely as time?

**IDEAL OUTPUT IS:** 00:00

*I have read many questions on here but found none that target the specific issue of time on input fields.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution. Just add attribute type. This should also be applicable to normal html input fields.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Time" RunAt="Server" type="time"/>
```

Note: This may not be completely crossbrowser compatible.
Although my testing seems to say otherwise. Firefox does not support type field but still formats as below.

---

**INPUT**

**1900-01-01 00:00:00.000**

```
type="time"
```

outputs as:

**00:00:00**

```
type="date"
```

outputs as:

**1900-01-01**

Comment: Nice, never knew you could do that. Been a while since I've used web forms, all MVC now but nice to know.

Answer (score 2):

Why not convert it on the database side?  You do not perform a SELECT * because it sends over more data.  So, why not have the larger hardware, the database server do the work?

Here is TSQL code to do what you need.

```
-- date time variable
declare @dt as datetime;
set @dt = getdate();
print @dt

-- just return time as string
declare @txt as varchar(8);
set @txt = cast(@dt as time);
print @txt

-- sample use in query
select 
  cast(cast(getdate() as time) as varchar(8)) as answer
```

Message window output.

```
Jan 24 2014  9:23AM
09:23:47
```

Results window output.

[image]

I choose to return seconds.  If that is not the business rule, change to varchar(5).

Comment: This is how I would normally do it but as I mentioned I have heard fierce debate against it.

Comment: Please post some links.  I am a DBA/ETL guy but started in SW DEV.  I have done my share of C# and ASP .NET.  Always like to learn.

Comment: Sorry bud had a look cant find post again. They where all on stackoverflow... somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Convert` you can convert the string to a `Date` and format with `.ToString("t")`

**c#**

```
var aDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000");
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("t"));
```

**vb**

```
Dim aDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000")
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("t"))
```

This outputs `00:00`

If you wanted miliseconds you could use an uppercase T.

See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can this be added to the asp:textbox field instead of code behind or java?

Comment: It depends on how you are binding it I suppose. Are you thinking of a gridview in webforms? Here is an example for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029338/bind-to-textbox-with-string-format

Comment: It also has a bound column which you can specify direct in html markup, take a look here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @hutchonoid I was aware of dateformatstring but did not work outside of boundfield. Your answer does the job however I realized that simply adding type="time" does the same job. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Nice one, no problem.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 and about supports the FORMAT command.  However, it is slower than native TSQL since it uses the CLR which needs to be loaded during invocation.  It have the same options as the dataformatstring.